# Setting action with xbindkeys: sh: 1: Bad substitution and wrong clipboard area

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard, xbindkeys

I'm trying to copy the song info (artist - title) to the clipboard in xbindkeys using shell command and the banshee --query-title and --query-artist commands.

first I open the xbindkeys with

```
$ xbindkeys-config
```

Them I set them like so:

```
Name: Copy Song
Key: Control+Mod2 + apostrophe | m:0x14 + c:49
Action: artist=$(banshee --query-artist);title=$(banshee --query-title);echo ${artist:7} - ${title:7} | xsel
```

But there two problems with that.

**First problem**, when I execute the action it says `sh: 1: Bad substitution`, I test this command in the terminal and it runs fine, but when I run it in xbindkeys it doesn't.

If I change it to

```
Action: artist=$(banshee --query-artist);title=$(banshee --query-title);echo $artist- $title | xsel
```

It works fine, except it doesn't strip the unwanted parted of the string, instead of `The Beatles - I Want To Tell You` I get : `artist: The Beatles - title: I Want To Tell You`

**Second problem** is that it doesn't copy to the clipboard (ctrl+v) as expected, it copies to the middle mouse button clipboard (which is annoying), I tried using `xclip` but the result is the same.

How to fix those two problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to fix both problems.

For the **clipboard problem**, I installed the ClipIt `sudo apt-get install clipip` and in the preferences I **checked Use ctrl+c** and **unchecked Use Primary (Selection)**

The problem with the **shell command** not getting the sub-string properly I used `sed` instead:

```
artist=$(banshee --query-artist);title=$(banshee --query-title);echo $artist - $title | sed -e "s/title: //g" | sed -e "s/artist: //g" | xsel
```

This is probably a lot bad, but works.

If anyone have a more elegant version, feel free to post.